# How to distribute Cognos components on different operating systems?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I have a Content Manager and a Dispatcher each on a Linux server. I want to install the Gateway competent on a windows server so I can use IIS as the web application server. Is this possible?

Cognos Version: 11.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Cognos 11, a gateway is not strictly required. You could certainly use IIS as a reverse proxy for your Linux dispatchers, in other words treat IIS as an external load balancer, and use IIS as the URL to access Cognos.

One reason to use an IIS gateway is to achieve single signon (SSO). The standard Windows mechanism for SSO is Kerberos, and that requires the Content Manager to also be on Windows, as stated here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.doc/c_enabling_single_signon_between_actdirsrv_and_cog_comp.html

The documentation link above lists a 2nd way to achieve SSO using the REMOTE_USER environment variable. It sounds like that might be possible using just an IIS web server in front of other components running on Linux, but I can't personally vouch for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, but I don't have a need to do so -- so I have not read any documentation regarding that.  I would expect the components would communicate via defined rules that would be platform independent.

If you have the license capacity (like a per-user Analytics Administrator license), you should just try it.  Be sure to report back so we all know if it works.